# Lotus notes html email problem

Tags: css, email, lotus-notes, html-email

I've made an html email but unfortunately, my client uses a lotus 6.5 which renders css and other stuffs poorly. Now I've fixed most of it, except for one problem, it generated a huge spacing in the bottom part. It almost like a 
 when you look at it in Lotus notes but when i put in a border=1 inside the table, it produced a somewhat hollow spacing. Anyone one encountered this?

Heres a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlss8.png

For reference, here is what it should look like:
http://www.interfaceflor.asia/oi_buzz/apr/english.html

Any help would be appreciated. Its making me nuts for days now. Thanks. :)

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is likely Lotus Notes here and not your code. Notes is very buggy and non-standard when it comes to rendering HTML emails.

My advice is to stay away from using CSS if you want to have it render correctly.  Use tables and perhaps image sizes to control spacing.

Or just explain to the client they need to accept these inconsistencies as long as they are using an email client from 2005.

If you can share some code too we might be able to be more specific.

Comment: I'm not picking on your client there, by the way. My company is still using version 6.0.4!  But not for email anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Lotus Notes can't display a border small than 5 pixels. If you need a 1px border, you can save the line as an image, and use that instead.

Comment: Try using: `border="0"` on the table formatting and `border:none;` `border:1px solid black;` in CSS for the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes has been stripping all CSS in my HTML emails as well. I have included external style, embedded style and inline style. Most email clients at least honor inline style typcially. Notes has other plans in mind for all of my CSS, namely, not using it at all. The email looks great in nearly every other email client.

My suggestion is to write solid, semantically correct code with as much HTML text as possible. That way, the client will hopefully be able to at least read your content. Most importantly, I would suggest including a clear "web only version" link at the top of the page. Most email marketing services (Constant Contact, Createsend, etc.) will offer you this option. This is a surefire way that the client will be able to see your layout as it was intended to be seen. Unfortunately, this isn't the slickest and most ideal solution.