# Thick white borders when forwarding an email containing tables with Lotus

Tags: html, html-table, border, html-email, lotus

I have been working on an emailing project for a client using Lotus. Since they want each associate to be able to send a nice looking email individually, we first opted for a solution where we would design an email template, send it to the people meant to use it, and have them send an email using this template, by forwarding / cleaning up the headers and filling out a personal message in a specified area of the table.

Easy enough to accomplish for Outlook users.

But with Lotus (I believe they are using a very old version, running on windows XP), every time you forward an email containing table, all borders of the table appears as thick white lines, even though `border="0"` has been specified. It's quite an issue since our email has a dark background. Email does look ok upon reception, when it was send from an html mailer form example.

Do you know any html code trick to work one's way around this filthy bug ?

Answer (score 2):

Lotus 8.5 continues to have this problem.  The original email looks nice/professional.  However upon forwarding in Notes, the borders are very thick, the font is larger, and there are --you'll love this one-- thin blank lines between each original line.

Notes is a great workflow/database system, however their email client continues to be very problematic/substandard.  My company is switching to Outlook for all 13,000 employees this year.  This happened at a prior company I worked and as well.  It's really a shame, because Notes has been truly a superior product to Outlook for medium to large size companies for for the 13 years I have worked with both (Notes has had very good capabilities for index/search, workflow, and global offices). The best combination seems to be Outlook email client and Notes backend.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the customer to upgrade to a recent version of Notes & Domino. The HTML rendering & handling in Notes significantly improved with version 8.

2) This seems to be a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632459/lotus-notes-html-email-problem) with the version 6.5 Notes client.

Comment: This not wrong in it itself, but it's not realistic to get a client to change such a huge part of its software equipment. :(

Comment: Camille, as a consultant, ... you should advise your customer to use current, maintained software and not old software, where no updates, security fixes or functional enhancments are provided.